# How to prevent the removal of all images on click of a button in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

When I click on any of the buttons on the webpage, all the images present in the web page is getting removed automatically, how to prevent this behaviour?

please help.

Here is the onclick function which is getting called:-

```
function func7(){
    $('#datetimepicker12').css({"display":"none"});
    $('#sidediv').css({"display":"none"}); */
    $('body').append('<div id="sidediv1" style="position:absolute;top:85px;height:961px;width:361px;background: #FFFFFF;z-index:1;"><div id="coldiv" style="position: absolute;top: -1px;left:-28;height: 961px;width: 100px;border-right: 3px solid #E3E3E3;background: #FCFCFC;"><span id="caltitle" style="-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);-o-transform: rotate(90deg);-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);transform: rotate(270deg);white-space:nowrap;display:block;bottom:0;top: 90px;left: 35px;position: absolute;width:20px;height:20px;font-family: Dax-Regular;font-size: 24px;">Calendar</span><button type="submit" id="collapse2" style="position: absolute;top: 15px;left: 78px;border: 1px solid #E3E3E3;width: 42px;height: 20px;background: #FFFFFF;border-radius: 5px;" onClick="func12();"><img src="${ctxRoot}/images/calendar_icon.png" style="position: absolute;left: 2px;top: 2px;"/><img src="${ctxRoot}/images/rightarrow.png" style="position: absolute;left: 20px;top: 2px;" /></button><div></div>');
if((collapse1==1)&&(collapse2==1)){
    $('#gview_list').css({"overflow":"visible","left":"0%"});
    $('#list td[aria-describedby="list_Total"]').css({"border-right":"3px solid #e3e3e3"});
    $('table.ui-jqgrid-ftable td[aria-describedby="list_Total"]').css({"border-right":"3px solid #e3e3e3"})
    if(no_ofprojects>=6){
        $('#gview_list').css({"overflow":"visible","position":"absolute","left":"4.9%"});
        $('#gbox_list').css({"overflow":"visible","position":"absolute","left":"-7%"});
        }
}
else{
    $('#gview_list').css({"left":"0px"});
    if(no_ofprojects>5)
        $('#gview_list').css({"overflow":"scroll"});    
    $('#list td[aria-describedby="list_Total"]').css({"border-right":"none"});
    $('table.ui-jqgrid-ftable td[aria-describedby="list_Total"]').css({"border-right":"none"})
}
}
```

Thanks,
Poorna.

Comment: can you post the codes?

Comment: i have shared the code

Comment: in which HTML element you have the images? '#sidediv'?

Comment: Whats up with all this js, are you trying to write your css in js ?

Comment: no, I have the images in other div elements, not in sidediv .

Comment: can you use developer tools and check what is the change you see in image tags before and after click?

Comment: I ckecked.Before button click, i see the image tags in place.But, once button is clicked , the image tags are removed.